# Any Python alternatives to Selenium for programmatically logging into websites that require JavaScript for login?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I’m writing a little private app to automatically log into my internet banking every day, and download the latest transactions. I’m writing it as a Django app, so I’m working in Python.

My internet banking doesn’t seem to work without JavaScript — I think it uses JavaScript to assign a session ID of some sort. Fetching the sign-in page via `httplib` gives me a page telling me JavaScript’s required.

So, I’m now looking for libraries that fetch web pages, **and** execute the JavaScript on them. Pretty much headless browsers.

I’m fiddling about [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) at the moment. I think it’ll do the job, although it is designed for testing web apps, so I was wondering if there was anything with similar capabilities designed for more general purposes than testing.

Any Python alternatives to Selenium for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

since you use selenium I think you have already installed firefox. if so get an extension like firebug or tamper data and see what http-requests the javascript code will do while logging in.

if you have the url and the parameters needed you can easily program a python client with httplib or urllib2.

in firebug you find the requested urls under "NET". tamper data will be self descriptive. ;-)

Comment: That is indeed what I ended up doing — turns out in this case, the JavaScript wasn’t doing anything complicated.

That said, after a weekend of screen-scraping, I *really* hope they don’t upgrade the website front end, at least without also providing an API.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/). There is a [nice tutorial here](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/).

Alternatively, you can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get the page contents and something like [python-spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/) to run the scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good match for your problem is [Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/): a simple scripting language for Web browsing.

An other one to check is [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/) (a kind of Selenium but all written in Python).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Spynner](https://github.com/kiorky/spynner), it allows programmatic web browsing.

Comment: Lol @webaholik, when I posted this originally, I'm not even sure if Github existed. Thank you for editing the link

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [QtWebKit](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/) is another option.

Answer (score -2):

Since BeautifulSoup is no longer being actively developed I would recommend [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) since it does all the things that BeautifulSoup can do and a lot more.

Comment: Beautiful seems to be actively developed now https://code.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup

Comment: BeautifulSoup is more of a web page parser than automater